# can not render online resources or simple text in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

I have a view which I want to display some resources online. So I create a subclass of `android.view.View` and override the `dispatchDraw` method:

```
public class TView extends View {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    private Paint p = new Paint();

    public TView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        client.get("http://developer.android.com/assets/images/dac_logo.png", new BinaryHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] arg0) {
                doRender(canvas, arg0);
            }
        });
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void doRender(Canvas c, byte[] data) {
        Log.d("xx", "data length :" + data.length);
        c.drawText("hello", 10, 10 + p.getTextSize(), p);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
        bd.draw(c);
    }
}
```

However the following codes does not work.

I only got the log message :

```
04-18 19:10:44.933: D/xx(1258): data length :2170
```

It seems that the data is downloaded. But the  canvas does not render it.

What is the problem?

BTW,I use the [AsycHttpClient](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) to simplify the data request.

Comment: Any chance your custom view has a width/height of zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the asker of this post. And I find a so said solution. ( I do not if this is the best but I do works).

---

It seems that this is caused by the asynchronous thread when I tried to request data by the `AsyncHttpClient`. And once the requesting thread start, the UI thread is complete and returned back, and the `canvas` have got out of its scope.

Then when the data is returned back, the `canvas` would not work any more.

BTW, I still hope for a convinced answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
//                          ^^^^^
```